# Aligning 2 background images

Tags: css, image, bootstrap-4, background-image

I am trying to find a way to align 2 background images in separate containers. As you will see in the snippet I have a shape over 2 background images that doesn't correctly align. The curve should align perfectly over both containers.

I was able to get the shapes to align using a min-height on the second 'OverviewContent' section but the problem is that when i take this off it completely ruins the alignment. And I want the sections to be responsive.

**IN SHORT** I want 2 sections that have 2 seperate background images but the images have to align perfectly, how can I do this? (Both sections will change height depending on the content in the section at the time)

Let me know if anyone has any ideas. Cheers

```css
.technology-overview-header .headerPad {
    background: url("https://assets.testcre8.co.uk/images/mcauliffe-technology-header-image.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: auto;
    min-height: 496px;
    background-size: auto 100%, cover;
}

.introHeader1.dzsparallaxer .headerPad {
    padding: 134px;
}

.OverviewContent {
    background: url("https://assets.testcre8.co.uk/images/about-mcauliffe-background-image.jpg") no-repeat center;
        background-size: auto;
    background-size: cover;
}

.OverviewContent {
    padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Header Image -->
  <section class="introHeader1 technology-overview-header dzsparallaxer auto-init height-is-based-on-content use-loading mode-scroll loaded dzsprx-readyall g-topSec-mt-ipad" data-options='{direction: "fromtop", animation_duration: 25, direction: "reverse"}' style="margin-top: 112px;"> 
    <div class="container-fluid g-color-white headerPad">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </section>
  <!-- End Header Image --> 
  
    <!-- Content -->
  <section class="OverviewContent g-pb-200">                    
    <div class="container">  
      <div class="row breadcrumb-trail">
       <div class="col-12 g-pb-200 g-pt-20">
        <p><a href="/" title="McAuliffe Website Homepage">Home</a> / Our Projects</p>   
       </div>           
      </div>        
      <div class="row"> 
        <!-- Info Blocks -->
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h2>H2 title goes here</h2>           
          <div class="row list-unstyled">
            <div class="col-lg-6 g-mb-20">
              <p class="introText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquam tempor magna, et congue velit sodales eu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquam tempor magna, et congue velit sodales eu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 g-mb-20">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquam tempor magna, et congue velit sodales eu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquam tempor magna, et congue velit sodales eu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
            </div>
          </div>                   
        </div>
        <!-- End Info Blocks --> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End Content -->
```

Comment: As an alternative, can it be a single background image on a 'wrapper' container, or [multiple background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds) on a single 'wrapper' container?

Comment: Hi @CraftedPod I guess it could be but I thought that 2 separate containers with separate background images would be a better way to control it. Both sections will have content in them so don't really want to be fussing around with padding/margin to separate both sections.